# Python Official Stripe Client Creating Two Customers

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, stripe-payments

This code I'm using below works perfectly, except when checkout is complete I have noticed two customer entries are being made every time someone checkouts on my site.

One has the default source set and one does not. I have attached a screenshot.

https://i.ibb.co/8dd0Cxz/Screenshot-from-2020-04-20-11-15-25.png

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        plan = Plan.objects.get(nickname=request.POST['plan'])
        stripe_customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email=request.user.email, source=request.POST['stripeToken'])

        stripe_subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(customer=stripe_customer.id,
                                                         items=[
                                                             {'plan': plan.id}],
                                                         trial_from_plan=True)
        # Tried removing but no the reason for the issue.
        Subscription.sync_from_stripe_data(
            stripe_subscription
        )
        return redirect('settings')
    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            plan = Plan.objects.get(nickname=request.GET['plan'])
        return render(request, 'plans/checkout.html',
                      {'plan': plan, 'price': '0'})
```

I have tried changing {'plan': plan.id} to {'plan': plan} and I get error:

Request req_0WL0lW2orGwLMV: No such plan: Family; one exists with a name of Family, but its ID is plan_H5fvA8jJ0qX9qF.

**edit:** dj-stripe+webhooks is in use but I need to create the customer using the official API. It seems the duplicate customer (with no payment source) is being created last after (for some reason) creating the subscription

Comment: If you look at the Customer object in the Stripe dashboard, there's a Logs section that will how you which API request created it. That's a good starting point to see what request created it and track that back through your code.

Comment: I'm digging. It seems the duplicate customer (with no payment source) is being created last after (for some reason) creating the subscription.

Comment: It might be that the user double clicks on the frontend, or the frontend sends a request twice, and you end up calling `stripe.Customer.create` but with a nil POST body or without a token.

Comment: Nah it's me testing. I wouldn't rule out the HTML/JS doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        plan = Plan.objects.get(nickname=request.POST['plan'])

        # Create the stripe Customer, by default subscriber Model is User,
        # this can be overridden with settings.DJSTRIPE_SUBSCRIBER_MODEL
        stripe_customer, _ = Customer.get_or_create(
            subscriber=request.user)

        # Using the Stripe API, create a subscription for this customer,
        # using the customer's default payment source
        stripe_subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(customer=stripe_customer.id,
                                                         items=[
                                                             {'plan': plan.id}],
                                                         trial_from_plan=True)

        # Add the source as the customer's default card
        stripe_customer.add_card(request.POST['stripeToken'])

        # Sync the Stripe API return data to the database,
        # this way we don't need to wait for a webhook-triggered sync
        Subscription.sync_from_stripe_data(
            stripe_subscription
        )
        return redirect('settings')
    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            plan = Plan.objects.get(nickname=request.GET['plan'])
        return render(request, 'plans/checkout.html',
                      {'plan': plan, 'price': '0'})
```